# Touch position on xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

*Do Xamarin provides touch position/gesture API ?
*Do MR.Gestures is the best solution to handle touch ?
*Is there other touch shared code APIs ?
*Or simply, how can I get the coordonates of all touched points with Xamarin ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a better explanation of your use case.

Comment: [Xamarin TouchTrackingEffect Sample](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/Effects/TouchTrackingEffect), described at [Invoking Events from Effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/touch-tracking) is one open-source approach. its also available as [a (not official) Nuget](https://github.com/zauberzeug/XFormsTouch).

Comment: emmm, are you copying the questions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186122/xamarin-how-to-get-cursor-touch-coordinates-position-x-and-y)

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin forms built in gesture recognizers provide basic touch handling currently.So externel Api is a choice.

Although you can use dependency service to subscribe/unsubscribe to the tap events. Here is a question you can refer to [Xamarin.Forms - Global tapped event on application level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215689/xamarin-forms-global-tapped-event-on-application-level).